# Salesforce Trigger workflow on record delete

Tags: salesforce

I want to listen change in my legacy system whenever there is any change in SF object (add/update/delete). So I have created outbound message and workflow. But in workflow I don't see any way to fire if object is deleted.

Is there anyway I can trigger outbound message on record delete? I know have heard that it can be done by trigger. But I don't want to write apex code for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge it cannot be done, the workflow actions are decoupled from the workflow rule (you can even reuse them) so they probably do not receive the transaction scope and when they execute the record is already gone and any reference inside action would point to a non-existing data. Thus the only way I know how to do it is via trigger.

Comment: Great explanation! I agree, you'd have to write a delete trigger. Here's a [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_defining.htm) to the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround. However this will only be able to capture deletion made via std. Salesforce UI.

1.Create a custom checkbox field "Is Deleted" 
2.Override the Del link with a custom VF page, that first updates the record status to "Is Deleted", and deletes the record. 
3.Write workflow rule using the "Is Deleted" field.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a compromise architecture would be to write an extremely small and simple after delete trigger that simply copies the deleted records in question to some new custom object. That new custom object fires your workflow rule and thus sends the outbound message you're looking for. The only issue with this would be to periodically clean up your custom object data that would grow in size as you deleted records from your other object. In other words, your "scratch" object would just need periodic cleaning - which could be done on a nightly schedule with batch Apex.

Here's a delete trigger that would do the trick using Opportunity as an example:

```
trigger AfterDelete on Opportunity (after delete) 
{
    List<CustObj__c> co = new List<CustObj__c>();
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.old)
    {
        CustObj__c c = new CustObj__c();
        c.Name = o.Name;
        c.Amount__c = o.Amount;
        c.CloseDate__c = o.CloseDate;
        c.Description__c = o.Description;
        // etc.

        co.add(c);
    }

    insert co;
}
```

It's not ideal but at least this would save you from having to code your own trigger-based outbound messages. These can only be done using the @Future annotation, btw, since callouts directly from triggers are forbidden. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

write a single email send in the trigger delete event. You have it in less than 1 hour.

Comment: Can you provide an example or some additional information on how to create a trigger delete event?, your answer reiterates part of the question "I know have hear that it can be done by trigger"